# Which Wiki integrates the best with atlassian

Tags: wiki

The company i work for recently  migrated most of working platforms to atlassian such as (bitbucket, jira and more).
Our wiki is very old and not user friendly, which wiki platform would you suggest to use?

Comment: Did you look at confluence of Atlassian?

Comment: Yes, forgot to note that we use trac wiki and the new one has to be easy to migrate to, need to be able throwing all our data to new wiki easily